# Winforms: Missing operand after 'Number' operator

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to bind my `textbox1` with the `datagridview2` so that the textbox can filter the row when the value in textbox and datagridview matches. However, I kept getting the above error. Below is my code

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     (dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Vehicle Number LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text); //error here
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space in your column name and thus you will have to escape it. probably like

```
"[Vehicle Number] LIKE '%{0}%'"
```